How to get the selected parts via VBA win explore mode Catia 3DX?
I explored an assembly, I had a simple code to get the names of the parts I wanted.
Dim oSel as Selection
set oSel = CATIA.ActiveEditor.Selection
oSel.Search "type=*,all"

On the tree, I saw all the parts being selected. However, when I tried oSel.Count, it returned 0 so I could not loop through my selection to get the names of the parts selected. Not sure what I did wrong.

Perhaps you exceeded the number of elements it could select in one go. You did search for "type=*,all" after all and that would include every feature inside every part in your assembly.  Use the interactive search editor to compose a query restricted to just what you want.  in V5 for example, such a search would be something like "'Assembly Design'.Part,all".
